# Conditions met but function not being called (Basic JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to put together a simple quiz to develop my basic JS skills, and it's all working ok, except for the 'endQuiz' function which for some reason isn't working.

As far as I can see, the conditions are being met but the function 'endQuiz' still isn't being called.

Any ideas why?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HVLvQ/ (gets to end of quiz and won't call endQuiz())

Here's the if statement

```
if (qNum === quizLength && isQuestion === false) {
    endQuiz();
}
```

and here's the function I want that to call:

```
function endQuiz() {
     questionBox.innerHTML = '<h1>Final Score:</h1>';
     answerBox.innerHTML = '<h2>' + score + ' out of ' + allQuestions.length + '</h2>';
     qNum = 0;
     score = 0;
}
```

Comment: Try an alert(); before the endQuiz(); ?

Comment: if I run alerts on the page that should call the endQuiz, both the conditions alert correctly, which is why I'm baffled.

Comment: How do you know the conditions are being met? Try what Will said to be sure.

Comment: Line 118: `var rightAnswer = allQuestions[qNum].correctAnswer;`.  If you are at the end of the quiz, qNum === allQuestions.length, so `allQuestions[qNum]` is undefined. Cannot access `undefined.correctAnswer`.

Comment: As a note, lines 128-132 can be replaced with simply `isCorrect = (chosen === rightAnswer);`

Comment: That's why people put JS consoles in their browsers: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'correctAnswer' of undefined*, with a clickable link that shows you the exact line. If you hope to write programs, you should learn about debugging tools.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. This seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/HVLvQ/5/

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to read `correctAnswer` from undefined in `checkAnswer()`.

Alter your `checkAnswer()` function so it checks if the question exists.

```
function checkAnswer() {

    if (allQuestions[qNum] == undefined) {
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

And it will work.

Comment: It's a good solution. It's good to see you thought about the problem and fixed it in your own way.